# List of HashMaps Java

Tags: java, list, hashmap, stanford-nlp

```
Map<String, List<String>> words = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            List<Map> listOfHash = new ArrayList<Map>();

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    String word = getTagValue("word", eElement);
                    List<String> add_word = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String pos = getTagValue("POS", eElement);
                    if(words.get(pos)!=null){
                        add_word.addAll(words.get(pos));
                        add_word.add(word);
                    }
                    else{
                        add_word.add(word);
                    }
                    words.put(pos, add_word);
                }
            }
```

This is a segment of code I have written (it uses Stanford CoreNLP). The problem I am facing is that presently this code is working only with one Map i.e. "words". Now, I want that as soon as the parser sees "000000000" which is my delimiter, then a new Map should be added to the List and then the keys and values to be inserted into it. If it does not see "000000000", then the Keys and Values are to be added in the same Map.
Please help me with that as I am not able to do it even after a lot of efforts.

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess listOfHash is to contain all your Maps...

So rename `words` to `currentMap` for example and add to it. When you see "000000000" instantiate a new Map, assign it to `currentMap`, add it to the list and go on...

something like:

```
if ("000000000".equals(word)){
    currentMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    listOfHash.add(currentMap);
    continue; // if we wan't to skip the insertion of "000000000"
}
```

And don't forget to add your initial Map to listOfHash.

I also see you have other problems with your code, here is modified version (I have not tried to compile it):

```
Map<String, List<String>> currentMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<Map> listOfHash = new ArrayList<Map>();
listOfHash.add(currentMap);


for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        String word = getTagValue("word", eElement);    

        if ("000000000".equals(word)){
            currentMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            listOfHash.add(currentMap);
            continue; // if we wan't to skip the insertion of "000000000"
        }

        String pos = getTagValue("POS", eElement);

        List<String> add_word = currentMap.get(pos);
        if(add_word==null){
            add_word = new ArrayList<String>();
            currentMap.put(pos, add_word);
        }
        add_word.add(word);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanx a lot pgras.. but what do you actually mean by "don't forget to add your initial Map to listOfHash". Can you please explain a little?

Comment: I need to replace "words" with "currentMap" right coz u haven't done it here. and thanx a lot